# Managing multiple applications developed in Play framework

Tags: playframework

We have various applications developed using PHP and Java. We are using apache and tomcat. So when when we restart the system, the PHP apps are up once apache is up and the Java apps are up once tomcat is up. I am not sure what is the best way to handle this in Play framework (Let's say we have 10+ Play applications). Certainly starting each app individually is not the right solution. We can write some start up script that start each application after reboot. But I am curious to know how developers using other but similar frameworks like ROR and Django handle this scenario. Are there any tools for this? Any tools that can be used for Play applications?

Answer (score 4):

Deploying WAR packages has some disadvantages, I can not discuss about performance but as you can see at the compatibility matrix of [WAR plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) there are still some unsupported features. So WAR should be considered as the last option (if no other available)

Currently I have the same set, PHP sites working via Apache + stand alone Play applications. Of course all of them need to be available on custom domain/subdomain on default web-port (80).

In very general: we are deploying apps on dedicated IP, which is controlled in the frontend by `nginx` server for proxy purposes and load balancing. Thanks to this we can start the application even in development mode on the server and it will be available at its domain. Of course if you haven't additional IP's you can also use Apache as a proxy however as far as I know `nginx` or `lighthttpd` are just much faster for this task.

You can find more details in the [Set-up a front-end server](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/HTTPServer) doc.

Now, using some simple bash scripts and git hooks you are able to prepare and deploy your application on the remote machine without need of resending whole package (which has size ~50mb for small app). Just similar to Heroku deployment, you should push to your server only the app's code, then using hook and script should prepare `dist` package ([more about dist](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ProductionDist)) and run it on some defined port, which will be available by proxy mentioned before.

Of course starting application via Play's console is unnecessary waste of memory in the production env.

There are samples on how to start Play apps on the server's start, so you'll probably find some tips according to your machine.

As far as I know this is most optimal scenario for now

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting on Ubuntu you are probably best served plugging in an init script ([this is a decent start](https://gist.github.com/1240920)) for each app, that way they'll start up with the machine.

Alternatively https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin looks like it will let you send Play 2 apps to a WAR file you can deploy in Tomcat: core support for WAR deployment in the Play 2 series is not scheduled to show up till 2.1, so you may not be able to get that to work. Play 1 natively supports it: just go

```
play war myapp -o myapp.war
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am aware of the war solution. But Play framework developers suggest using the in-built server for better performance. Init script is another solution (which I also mentioned in my post). But still I feel there must be better way. That's why I wanted to know how it is done in ROR or Django world.